# Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set does not exists?) in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, importexport

I have a products exported file from Magento 1.14 EE and I want it to import in magento 1.9 CE.

When I am trying to upload that I'm getting following error:

> Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set does not exists?) in rows:
>   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
>   21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44,
>   45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61,
>   62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78,
>   79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95,
>   96, 97, 98, 99, 100 Orphan rows that will be skipped due default row
>   errors in rows: 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32

Comment: Error is something related to attribute set. Recheck the attribute set column and update it accordingly then try again.

Comment: please check attribute set value and csv format.

Comment: Check the attribute set name in admin and put it in your csv file.

Comment: Just in case anybody comes across the same issue I had when getting this error. Make sure your 'Default' text has a capital D not like this 'default' as it needs to be exact case specific.

Answer (score 0):

Naveen, when you import products using a csv Magento checks the value you used in the `_attribute_set` column. If there isn't an attribute set with that name in your CE instance then it will show that error. 
Go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute sets to see what this value should be. If it is a brand new CE installation it will probably be called Default.

Note, that when you fix this issue you may find you have problems with attribute names if you haven't recreated those in your CE installation to match the ones in your EE.

Comment: still I am getting the same error after setting Default as `_attribute_set ` value. Can you help me out with this please.

Comment: Can you post your csv somewhere?

Comment: To import products through Magento Default Import Process, "attribute_set_code" is a required entity to define in sheet(CSV) with valid value. In most cases the value of it could be "Default" but check it from Admin -- Store -- Attributes -- Attribute Set and make sure you opt the correct on which you are going to create products.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.4.6 the column with the attribute set needs to be named "attribute_set_code".

So, the complete crosscheck would need to include:

1. Your input file should have column "attribute_set_code".
2. The values in the columns should match the "Set" column in Stores -> Attributes -> Attribute Set